# Are atoms in a perfect crystal lattice indistinguishable?

Tags: crystals, identical-particles

So I was reading a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics) about the third law of thermodynamics, and was intrigued by the following sentences:

Suppose a system consisting of a crystal lattice with volume V of N identical atoms at T= 0 K, and an incoming photon of wavelength λ and energy ε.

Initially, there is only one accessible microstate ...

Let's assume the crystal lattice absorbs the incoming photon. There is a unique atom in the lattice that interacts and absorbs this photon. So after absorption, there is N possible microstates accessible by the system, each of the microstates corresponding to one excited atom, and the other atoms remaining at ground state.

My question is: aren't these N atoms indistinguishable, and therefore why would there be N microstates, instead of 1? In other words, why would the microstate that atom i absorbed the photo be different than the microstate that atom j absorbed the photo (i!=j)?

Thanks!

Atuzai

Comment: No, in a lattice the electronic band structure, a product of the whole assemblage of atoms, would absorb the photon.